# Android, prevent to kill service/thread

Tags: android, multithreading, service

how can i prevent this service with thread to dont be killed from android, i need this notifications always runnig, but when is mobile locked, nothing will happen. I think android kill service or thread or something like that

MainActivity in onCreate

```
startService(new Intent(this, NotifyService.class));
```

My service

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

private DatabaseOp mDbHelper;
public Vibrator vibrator;

String username;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate ()
{
    mDbHelper = new DatabaseOp(this);
    final boolean cyklus = true;

    Thread vlakno = new Thread (new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (cyklus)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String sysDate = getSysDate();
                String sysDate2 = getSysDate2();
                String time = getSysTime();

                mDbHelper.open();

                Log.v( "sysDate", sysDate );

                Cursor cursorU = mDbHelper.fetchUlohaS(0, sysDate);
                if (cursorU.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    String idU = cursorU.getString(cursorU.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_ID));
                    String dbDateU = cursorU.getString(cursorU.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_DATE));
                    String menoU = cursorU.getString(cursorU.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_NAZOV));

                    String mHodina = getResources().getString(R.string.cas)+" "+cursorU.getString(cursorU.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_HODINA));

                    Log.v( "task", dbDateU+"/"+sysDate );

                    if (dbDateU.equals(sysDate))
                    {
                        Notify(menoU, mHodina, idU, 0);                 
                    }
                }

                Cursor cursorS = mDbHelper.fetchSviatokS(3, sysDate2);
                if (cursorS.getCount() > 0)
                {
                    String idS = cursorS.getString(cursorS.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_ID));
                    String dbDateS = cursorS.getString(cursorS.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_DATUM));
                    String menoS = cursorS.getString(cursorS.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseOp.KEY_NAZOV));

                    if (dbDateS.equals(sysDate2) && time.equals("09:00")) 
                    {
                        Notify(menoS,getResources().getString(R.string.title_section4), idS, 3);
                    }
                }
                mDbHelper.close();
            }
        }
    });

    vlakno.start();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use ForgroundService?

Checkout this repo for an example - https://github.com/supercurio/foreground-service-sample-app

Comment: but how, startforeground is only for notificactions no ? ... i need to prevent kill a checking thread

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider `AlarmManager`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html.

Answer (score 0):

To tip the system to keep your `Service` alive as long as possible (i.e. before RAM is very short or user kills the service by hand through application info screen), you need to run it as a foreground service -- by using [startForeground()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) method.

If you're looking for a way to run when the device is turned off, read the [Keeping The Device Awake](http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html) training page and consider using `AlarmManager` instead as suggested by @khris if your task is not very critical in terms of timing precision.

Comment: This will not "ensure" that it is not killed - at best it may make it *less likely* but it is still very much killable, either under memory pressure or if the user swipes it out of recents.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I'll reword my answer, "ensure" may mislead someone. Still, that's the best one can do. Afaik, in earlier versions, foreground services were treated the same as foreground activities, now they have second best importance value, so memory pressure has to be critically heavy, one step short of system killing everything except, well, system. **> swipes it out of recents** -- not exactly, services are not necessarily killed, they just get notified the process is being killed. Try swiping out a music app while in playback, it's foreground service will keep playing.

Comment: WRT swpining out of recents, if the service is in a different process it may survive, but if it is as nomal in the same process it is killed along with everything else in that process, but may be quickly re-created.